# Countdown timer that syncs in different time zones

Tags: javascript, countdown

I'm trying to create a countdown for an event and I would like to know how to get it to sync with the different time zones.

Say the event is at 11 Am in Toronto and you are viewing it form somewhere else in the world, the countdown you see in your time zone should countdown to 11 AM London time.

I have only just started to code so the simpler the code the better.

This is the code I have so far

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    p {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 60px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="demo">
    <p class="DAYS" id="days">00</p>
    <p class="txt_DAYS">DAY</p>
    <p class="HRS" id="hours">00</p>
    <p class="txt_HRS">HRS</p>
    <p class="MINS" id="minutes">00</p>
    <p class="txt_MINS">MIN</p>
    <p class="SECS" id="seconds">00</p>
    <p class="txt_SECS">SEC</p>
    <p class="TEXT" id="Msg"></p>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 1, 2023 15:37:25").getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get today's date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Output the result in an element with id="demo"

      document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = (days < 10) ? ('0' + days) : days;
      document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = (hours < 10) ? ('0' + hours) : hours;
      document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = (minutes < 10) ? ('0' + minutes) : minutes;
      document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = (seconds < 10) ? ('0' + hours) : seconds;


      // If the count down is finished, write some text
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = (days < 10) ? ('0' + 00) : 00;
        document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = (hours < 10) ? ('0' + 00) : 00;
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = (minutes < 10) ? ('0' + 00) : 00;
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = (seconds < 10) ? ('0' + 00) : 00;
        document.getElementById("Msg").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 100);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are having>

Comment: First of all, don't depend on `new Date(string)` parsing your date correctly. Use `new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond)`, with `month` being the 0-based month number (Jan = 0, Dec = 11). Secondly, if you want to print "00", just use `"00"`, not `"0" + 00`... Finally, what makes you think it doesn't already work like you think? Have you tried changing your computer's time zone to London and looked at what your code produces?

Comment: @HereticMonkey

I did try 'Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond)' but the days were not displaying right. When I added the date as 2022,11,5 the countdown showed that there were 31 days left.

Also, I did get someone in a different timezone to check and even though it ended for me it was still counting down for them.

Comment: @gunwin

I'm trying to get the counter to countdown to my time zone for an event from whichever part of the world you check using your local time. I think it has to calculate the difference between my local time and the viewer's local time but I don't think it can be done with the code above.

Comment: There are 31 days between 2022-11-03 and 2022-12-05, so that seems correct... Dates, in JavaScript run in a browser, are created in the time zone of the browser unless you go out of your way to do otherwise.

Comment: @Matt Johnson-Pint wondering if you could help me out. I saw your reply on a different timezone question but couldn't under how to implement it. I just started coding so im still not familiar with lots of stuff.

Comment: @HereticMonkey 

The date i set was 2022-11-5  so that's 2 days.  2022-11-3 to 2022-11-5 and it showed up as 31 says remaining.

Comment: The date you set was December 5th, 2022 if you used the numbers 2022, 11, and 5 as the arguments to `new Date()`: look at my comment (and [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#monthindex)) again. 0 = January, 11 = December.

Comment: @HereticMonkey 
FACEPALM Im so sorry about that. it's counting down right now, Thank you!  

I still need to figure out the time zone difference though. I was reading about using this 
**var localtime=new Date(Date.UTC(year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds,msec))** but not sure how this will let other browsers know to count down to my timezone .

Wouldnt I first need to establish my timezone?